# Error starting apache web server

Tags: apache

I am trying to start my apache and its throwing the below error

"[Sat May 27 13:55:03 2017] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API"

Does someone have an idea of what is going own with my apache?

Comment: Just to get the situation clear. Can you post more info? Where are you trying to run it? Locally​? Windows machine? Your http config settings?

Comment: try `AcceptFilter http none` `AcceptFilter https none` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptfilter